# RDF or relational model, preferred development in Java

Tags: java, mysql, relational-database, rdf, apache-jena

I am planning to develop a web application in Java which could integrate:

- RDF data model (Protege 5) + Jena Engine + SPARQL 
  or
- Relational data model + MySQL + ORM library (such as MyBatis).

I wonder **which development could be faster** considering that **the data model must be created from scratch**. For instance, I have played a bit with Protege editor and it seems not to be quite easy to generate a fully operational model such as the one could be created using tables in a DBRMS.

I would need some comments to consider which is the best approach (currently, I would prefer to work with the relational data model).

Looking forward to hearing your comments.

Comment: I depends on what your web application will do. If your only requirement is to have a fast development process, then you should use the one you're most familiar with.

Comment: In my case the application should be ready in 3 months time and I have almost any experience with SPARQL+Jena+RDF. I am more experienced with the other alternative, so at the moment I would prefer to work with it.